# Does `ro` matter in CD-ROM mounts?

Tags: linux, mount, read-only

As far I know, `/dev/cdrom` usually provides a read-only device. However, some sources suggest to add `ro` in the `/etc/fstab` and others not.

Is there a difference between

`/dev/cdrom  /mnt/cdrom   auto    noauto,user          0 0`

and

`/dev/cdrom  /mnt/cdrom   auto    noauto,user,ro          0 0`

or will `mount` add always `ro`? And if so, from where does it exactly know that the device is read- only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference is that you get a message e.g.

```
mount: block device /dev/sr1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
```

'ro' avoids the message.

The device driver will tell the OS that the device is write protected.